# ExtJS 4 Grid with File Upload

Tags: gridview, file-upload, extjs4

It's possible to make GridPanel with File uploading.

I want to have GridPanel with some text columns and one column to upload a file.

```
dataIndex:'fieldForFile',
editor: {
  xtype:'filefield'
}
```

works but when I choose a file and renderer disappears, the record value is null.

Next step is to upload the files chosen in grid and at the moment I have no idea how to do it.

Can anyone help me ?

Greetings,
Pawel

Answer (score 2):

```
xtype:'actioncolumn',
width: 30,
text: '^',
align: 'center',
items: [{
    icon: '/Content/images/upload.png',  // Use a URL in the icon config
    tooltip: 'Upload',
    handler: function(grid, rowIndex, colIndex) {
             var uploadField = Ext.getCmp('uploadField');
             uploadField.fileInputEl.dom.click();
    }
}]
```